# Redirect all requests to a "site offline" page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, joomla

I need to do a complex release upgrade for my [Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/) site- since also the DB will be deleted and recreated I cannot use the builtin "Site offline" options.
I would rather need to redirect all traffic to my site to an offline.html page.

I'm testing this on my local backup with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^127.0.0.1:81/joomla [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:81/joomla/offline.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

However it doesn't seem to work: for example if I request

`http://127.0.0.1/joomla/administrator/`

then it turns into:

`http://127.0.0.1/offline.htmljoomla/administrator/`

Any help?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/joomla/offline.html$ 

RewriteRule $ /joomla/offline.html [R=302,L]
```